# How do I return combination of same level nodes in one webelement in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

my knowledge of selenium at this point is a bit limited, but from what I understand driver.find_elements_by_xpath() returns a list of webelements. One can then iterate over the elements and do whatever one wants, like printing text.
That part is easy. 
But now assume on a given page I would be looking for every combination of 3 nodes:

```
<parent>
   <h1>text</h1>
   <div class="identifier">more stuff</div>
   <h3>text2</h3>
   <h1>other text</h1>
   <div class="identifier">other more stuff</div>
   <h3>other text2</h3>
   ...
</parent>
```

These 3 nodes (here h1, div with class, and h3) are on the same level of hierarchy and there are many of them there since its a list. Is there a way to have selenium return them "packaged"? In this case I could make sure I get the correct data together. The way I am doing it right now is getting the middle element and then preceding and following sibling with the specified tag. But I feel like thats whacky at best.

Thx alot.

Comment: The best way to do this likely involves referencing a parent element to these sibling elements. Can you post some more of the surrounding HTML? You aren't going to be able to return these packaged straight from a single find using Selenium but you could write a function that takes the parent element and returns a collection of these three elements as a "package."

Comment: Thx Jeff. Thats what I thought. There is one problem though. The only parent contains a bunch of my 3 nodes combinations. I updated the description, does that answer your question sufficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what code you are using for your approach but I would do something like this.

```
headings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("parent > h1"))
for i in range(len(headings)):
    heading = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("parent > h1:nth-of-type(" + i + ")"))
    identifier = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("parent > div.identifier:nth-of-type(" + i + ")"))
    subheading = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("parent > h3:nth-of-type(" + i + ")"))
    // do something with each element here
```

Now you can reference each of the elements.

NOTE: This assumes that each of the elements always exists. If you are ever missing an `h3`, etc. this code will mismatch the groups.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I am doing something very similiar. my concern is exactly what you pointed out, but I guess there is no built in functionality in selenium to solve that problem.

Comment: You could add a validation before the loop that verifies that the count of h1s, div.identifier, and h3 are all equal. If they are not, throw an error ... or something to let you know that things are going to be off. At that point, I don't know what you would do. I'd have to see the HTML for myself to try to come up with some approach.

Comment: Ya, thats pretty much what I ended up doing. Thank you for backing up my approach though. Offtopic: I saw you where using css_selectors. I have been mostly using XPath so far. I did some reasearch and couldn't find a compelling reason to not use it (quite the contrary: e.g. "contains" doesn't work with css_selectors) Whats your take on this?

Comment: Anything is faster than XPath... and by faster I mean fractions of a second but everything adds up. If you can find the same element but find it faster, why wouldn't you? I prefer locators in this order: id, CSS selector, and then everything else until XPath. I only use XPath when I absolutely have to... using `text()` or `contains()` or some funky parent/sibling/etc thing that can't be done with CSS selectors. I think a lot of people use XPath because of Firebug, etc. They can right-click and get XPath. That generally leads to really bad and fragile XPaths and should be avoided but it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine -- just find the first element and then check to make sure the next one (and one after) are the ones you are expecting, otherwise continue searching.

For more complex cases like this, it might be easier to pull out the HTML of the body as text and run a (more powerful) regex on it.

Comment: You really, really don't want to regex HTML. I'm not sure what regex is going to do in this case that locators can't. Regex is a lot more likely to be really complicated and fragile.

Comment: For every problem one tries to solve with regex, he ends up with two new ones :)